# Removing part of a bunch of directory names using a wildcard

Tags: directory, rename

I am trying use unix to remove the last part of the names of a series of directories. Here is an example of the naming structure:

```
s23987_11.09.16_hf_0001
s29485_03.04.07_hs_0005
s39854_01.01.01_an_0011
```

I am trying to remove everything following the first _ such that the directory names would be:

```
s23987
s29485
s39854
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With POSIX shells:

```
for d in *_*; do mv -- "$d" "${d%%_*}"; done
```

The [`%%` syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) says "match as much as you can of: an underscore (`_`) followed by anything (`*`) from the end of the variable's value".